# Error sending Slack notification to private channel from appveyor

Tags: api, notifications, slash, appveyor

I tried to set up Slash notification to my private channel for [Appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/projects) using the following configuration (*xxxxxx* is my token encrypted [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/tools/encrypt)):

```
notifications:
  - provider: Slack
    channel: dev
    auth_token:
      secure: xxxxxx
```

My [Appveyor build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/MartinDelille/travistest/build/1.0.307) show me the folloing error:

```
Error sending Slack notification: Error sending Slack message: channel_not_found
```

When testing the Slash api with the following URL, it works: https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xxxxxx&channel=dev&text=hello&pretty=1 (where *xxxxxx* is my token without encryption).

It also works if the channel is not private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug that is now fixed: https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/623

Answer (score 1):

Try placing `#dev` into `channel` setting:

```
notifications:
  - provider: Slack
    channel: '#dev'
    auth_token:
      secure: xxxxxx
```

Also, instead of auth token try configuring it with [Incoming Webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) where channel is encoded in webhook URL.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I'll look the webhook.